# Retrieving values from dynamic checkbuttons

Tags: python, for-loop, tkinter, dynamic

I am using a for loop to create checkbuttons based off a list. I then want a button that'll "get" which buttons have been checked or not.

Since I am not manually creating the checkbuttons, I am not naming the variables so how can I .get() whether they are on or off?

Comment: Loop over your list and call `get()` on each index. `checkbuttonList[n].get()`

Comment: Store them in a list or dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks very much this worked nicely

'''
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

shopping = ['Apples','Pears','Bananas']

chbuttonlist = []

for item in shopping:

```
var = StringVar()
b = Checkbutton(root,text=item,variable=var)
b.deselect()
b.pack()
chbuttonlist.append(var)
```

def printlist():

```
lst=[]
for var in chbuttonlist:
    lst.append(var.get())

for i in range(len(lst)):
    if lst[i]=='1':
        print(shopping[i])
```

Button(root,text='Click to print checked items',command=printlist).pack()

root.mainloop()

'''